# Merge two GeometryArray into one one GeometryArray in geopandas?

Tags: geopandas

How can I merge two GeometryArray (available in GeoPandas)?

I have two Geometry arrays and I want to merge them to save them to a single file.

Sadly I get `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'GeometryArray' and 'GeometryArray'` and GeoPandas docs [are not helpful](https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/issues/1186).

```
data = gpd.read_file(in_file)

if "waterway" in data:
    rivers = []
    streams = []
    rivers = data[data["waterway"] == "river"]
    rivers.geometry = rivers['geometry'].buffer(0.000250)
    streams = data[data["waterway"] == "stream"]
    streams.geometry = streams['geometry'].buffer(0.000025)
    (rivers + streams).to_file(out_file, driver = 'GeoJSON')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copying the answer from GH issue:

You are looking for simple `append`. Reproducible example:

```py
world = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))
cities = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_cities'))
merged = world.geometry.append(cities.geometry)
```

Your example:

```py
data = gpd.read_file(in_file)

if "waterway" in data:
    rivers = []
    streams = []
    rivers = data[data["waterway"] == "river"]
    rivers.geometry = rivers['geometry'].buffer(0.000250)
    streams = data[data["waterway"] == "stream"]
    streams.geometry = streams['geometry'].buffer(0.000025)
    rivers.append(streams).to_file(out_file, driver = 'GeoJSON')
```